# Jmeter header manager reuse

Tags: jmeter

Im using Jmeter to write some load tests on an API secured by oAuth.
I want to be able to reuse the header manager once the bearer token has been produced from the access token call.

However when I try to move the header manager out side of the http request the call is no longer authorised. I think its because it can no longer get the bearer token.

[image]
For Post Request, when i put the header manager outside it no longer works, it only works when I put it under the request as I have done for User get request, Delete request and Put request.

How do I make the header manager reusable and therefore only manage one header manager?

Thank you.

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Invalid access token","detail":{"errorcode":"oauth.v2.InvalidAccessToken"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that this is due to clash with the [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

1. Both are [Configuration Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) and both obey [JMeter Scoping rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)
2. When you move HTTP Header Manager outside the HTTP Request sampler it might be the case that [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) Header comes from the HTTP Authorization Manager

You can check which exact header value is being sent using `Request -> Request Headers` tab of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

---

Given you manually create `Authorization` header for your request I believe if you disable or delete the HTTP Authorization Manager your test should start working as expected as you basically don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, I need the Authrorization manager in order to authenticate against the oAuth server. If i remove it then all the requests will fail.